# How to create django-filter custom filter for month/year for a dateField in model?

Tags: django, django-rest-framework, django-filter

I am trying to filter date based on its month and year. Below is what I tried. In models.py

```
class Expense(TimeStampedModel):date = models.DateField(_('date')
```

in serailizer.py

```
class ExpenseSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    class Meta:
        model = Expense
        fields = '__all__'
```

in filters.py

```
class ExpenseFilter(django_filters.FilterSet):
    date__month = django_filters.DateFilter(field_name='date',                  
    lookup_expr='month')
    date__year = django_filters.DateFilter(field_name='date', lookup_expr='year')
    class Meta:
        model = Expense
        fields = ('date__month', 'date__year')
```

In views.py

```
class ExpenseViewSet(viewsets.ModelViewSet):
    queryset = Expense.objects.all()
    serializer_class = ExpenseSerializer
    filter_class = ExpenseFilter
```

When I try to hit http://127.0.0.1:8000/expense/?date__year=2019 I get an empty result. Any help on this will be really appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

```
class CustomDateFilter(DateFilter):
    def filter(self, qs, value):
        if value:
            filter_lookups = {
                "%s__month" % (self.field_name, ): value.month,
                "%s__year" % (self.field_name, ): value.year
            }
            qs = qs.filter(**filter_lookups)
        return qs
```

```
class ExpenseDateFilter(FilterSet):
    date = CustomDateFilter(field_name='date')

    class Meta:
        model = Expense
        fields = ('project__id', 'date')
```

Answer (score 0):

Have you considered using a [`DateRangeFilter`](https://django-filter.readthedocs.io/en/master/ref/filters.html#daterangefilter)? It might be a better option for you. What it wouldn't do, but your proposed `ExpenseFilter` would is find expense instances for one month of all years.

Comment: As per my understanding, DateRangeFilter would work with two dates something like start/end date. I have only one date field in model.Also for my requirement, I have to filter expense based on month&year provided in date field. So, the url could be http://127.0.0.1:8000/expense/?date=2019-01-01 or http://127.0.0.1:8000/expense/?date__year=2019&date__month=01.

Comment: Ok, this worked for me.`class CustomDateFilter(DateFilter):

    def filter(self, qs, value):
        if value:
            filter_lookups = {
                "%s__month" % (self.name, ):value.month,
                
                "%s__year" % (self.name, ):value.year
            }
            qs = qs.filter(**filter_lookups)
        return qs


class ExpenseFilter(FilterSet):
    date = CustomDateFilter(name='date')

    class Meta:
        model = Expense
        fields = ('project__id', 'date')`Not sure if its the right way, but could'nt find anything else.